# How do I get string from DB in Default.aspx file?

Tags: c#, webforms

I am trying to display message on button click inside a popup window. Everything works fine except I can not get string from Database.

```
<button type="button" class="btn-outline" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content=<% LabelManager.Get("UnitPriceExplanation"); %>>
                    [?]
</button>
```

If I write random text inside data-content, it will work. If I put `<% LabelManager.Get("UnitPriceExplanation");` it will not display text. So it will not respond to click.

LabelManager.Get("UnitPriceExplanation"); works fine in Default.aspx.cs.

My goal is to write text from DB in popover window. How do I get string from Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Asp.Net while `<% %>` operators execute a block, `<%= %>` executes the code and prints the result. You need to use the later and wrap it in quotation marks.

```
data-content="<%= LabelManager.Get("UnitPriceExplanation") %>"
```